# How to get selected value from drodown of parent template in to the view in Django where template inheritance is used

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Just started learning Django where I faced this problem
I want to create eCommerce site where users can select their location(Like State & Area) and accordingly the products will be displayed to do this I have already created two drop downs in the navbar.html which is extended by the base.html which is extended by the home.html.

cart_template_tags.py:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def load_city(request):
    locations = Locations.objects.filter()
    return locations


@register.filter
def load_areas(request):
    locations = Area.objects.filter()
    return locations
```

navbar.html:

```
{% load cart_template_tags %}

      <form method="GET" action=".">
          <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
            <select id="city" class="form-control" name="city">
              <option selected>city...</option>
              {% for cityVal in request.user|load_city %}
              <option value="{{ cityVal }}">{{ cityVal }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <select id="area" class="form-control" name="area">
              <option selected>area...</option>
              {% for areaVal in request.user|load_areas %}
              <option value="{{ areaVal }}">{{ areaVal }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </form>
```

I have displayed products using home view where I rendered home.html
Views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"
```

how can I get the value which I have selected in drop down "city" & "area" in HomeView ?

If you have any suggestion please suggest or if you know any opensource code where this functionality (Location wise product display) is developed you can suggest that too